# SQL DISTINCT values across rows

Tags: sql

I have duplicate `agreementnumber` and duplicate `telephone` in columns and I want to get unique `agreementnumber` and it's corresponding unique `telephone` in columns.

I have written query in SQL which gives me unique `agreementnumber` but `telephone` in rows are duplicate but I want unique phone numbers.

code:

```
select agreementnumber,

  max(case when rn = 1 then telephone end) telephone1,

  max(case when rn = 2 then telephone end) telephone2,

  max(case when rn = 3 then telephone end) telephone3,

  max(case when rn = 4 then telephone end) telephone4,

  max(case when rn = 5 then telephone end) telephone5

from
(
  select agreementnumber, telephone,

    row_number() over(partition by agreementnumber order by telephone) rn
  from alternate_mobile 

) src
group by agreementnumber;
```

I want following output. Unique values in col1 and col2,col3,col4,col4.

col1   col2     col3   col4``
AGMTNO  phone1  phone2 phone3

Comment: You want to do something complicated but it seems to not be ... Give us a sample of your data and the wanted data set.

Comment: also please tag appropriate database name.

Comment: I think the example, in this case, although is always well received, is not totally necessary. It's cristal clear he wants to pivot the first 5 phones in 5 columns, discarding the rest, and removing those which are equals. You can prepare a basic set of data to test it.

Comment: AGREEMENTNUMBER TELEPHONE
TN3000CD0027934 8608766694
TN3000CD0027934 8608766694
AP3019CD0012936 9701256775
AP3075CD0029548 9701256775
AP3075CD0029548 9382615863
AP3075CD0029548 8768127359                                                                              This is sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this little change in your query:

```
select agreementnumber,
  max(case when rn = 1 then telephone end) telephone1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then telephone end) telephone2,   
  max(case when rn = 3 then telephone end) telephone3,
  max(case when rn = 4 then telephone end) telephone4,
  max(case when rn = 5 then telephone end) telephone5

from
(
  select x.*,
    row_number() over(partition by x.agreementnumber order by x.telephone) rn
  from (
    select distinct agreementnumber, telephone
    from alternate_mobile 
  ) x
) src
group by agreementnumber;
```

If you were getting duplicate telephones is because you have duplicated `agreementnumber`/`telephone` in your `alternate_mobile` table.

### Edited:

I change the query to keep just numbers in the telephone, removing all the rest of characters:

```
select agreementnumber,
  max(case when rn = 1 then telephone end) telephone1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then telephone end) telephone2,   
  max(case when rn = 3 then telephone end) telephone3,
  max(case when rn = 4 then telephone end) telephone4,
  max(case when rn = 5 then telephone end) telephone5

from
(
  select x.*,
    row_number() over(partition by x.agreementnumber order by x.telephone) rn
  from (
    select distinct agreementnumber, regexp_replace(telephone,'[^0-9]', '') as telephone
    from alternate_mobile 
  ) x
) src
group by agreementnumber;
```

Comment: I tried running code but giving error as missing expression at line from alternate_mobile. My databse is plsql

Comment: Sorry, there was an extra comma in the subquery, try it now

Comment: I need one more help please. In my data, some of mobile numbers are in different format like +91456235674,+91(456)235674 etc. also there are special characters in numbers also. How can I convert these only to numbers by removing all characters.

Comment: You can use a regular expression to replace all non numeric characters by ''. You must do it in the very inner subquery (the ‘distinct’ one)

Comment: Please provide modified query.

Comment: I change the query in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a note, you can reduce the number of subqueries by using `rank()` instead of `row_number()`:

```
select agreementnumber,
       max(case when rn = 1 then telephone end) as telephone1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then telephone end) as telephone2,   
       max(case when rn = 3 then telephone end) as telephone3,
       max(case when rn = 4 then telephone end) as telephone4,
       max(case when rn = 5 then telephone end) as telephone5
from (select am.*,
             rank() over (partition by am.agreementnumber order by am.telephone) as rn
      from alternate_mobile am
     ) am
group by agreementnumber;
```

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff. Totally agree, I just tried to modify his query the less as possible to allow him to recognize better what was wrong with his query

Comment: Hi Team, some of the mobile numbers start with 91 and causing mobile number as 12 digit. How to tackle this issue. Please suggest.

Comment: @vishal . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions, not in comments.  This question has already been answered.